# Posthoc analysis in lmm: unexecuted

Tags: r, lm, posthoc

I am trying to solve the error:

**Error in if ((misc$estType == "pairs") && (paste(c("", by), collapse = ",") !=  :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed**

My code:

```
model1 <- lmer (Y ~ X1 * X2 + (1|"FACTOR of 13 levels"), data=data, REML = FALSE)

library (emmeans)

post_hoc <- emmeans (model1, ~ X1*X2)

pairs (post_hoc, adjust="tukey")
```

But it returns the above error. I've tried to change the code, but I haven't succeeded.
Can someone help me solve it, please?

Comment: Try instead specifying `emmeans(model1, specs = revpairwise ~ X1 | X2)`.

Comment: @mhovd  R returns the same error. I noticed that there are no  `stats::pairs` (when I type `pairs ()` it shows `pairs {graphics}`, only)

Comment: My guess is that it will work if you use adjust = "mvt" instead. The error seems to be in code to see if Tukey is appropriate - which it appears to be, but there's some kind of snag. mvt will yield about the same adjustment.

Comment: BTW, I recommend fitting with REML = TRUE before doing post hoc analysis

Comment: @RuusLenth Still showing the same error :/

Comment: @MendesVinícius please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what is going on. I believe that `X1` and `X2` are both numeric predictors. Therefore, your `post_hoc` lists just one case -- the one where `X1` and `X2` are each at their mean value. Try this:

```
post_hoc
```

(Just type the name of the object and hit return. This will display it.)

I would bet money that there is just one case listed, but betting on this site is probably frowned upon. You can't compare one thing, and that's why you get an error.

If those predictors are really supposed to be factors, you need to fit a model that recognizes them as such, e.g.,

```
model2 <- lmer(factor(X1) * factor(X2) + (1|subject), 
               data = data, REML = TRUE)
```

Your `model1` is almost surely useless, because it fits the equation of a hyperbolic surface in two numeric variables.

I'll see if I can get `contrast()` and `pairs()` to display a more informative error message.

Comment: You're right, friend. I didn't pay attention to the fact that my X1 and X2 are numerical. However, I cannot transform them into factors as they are continuous values. I will close the question. Thanks!

Comment: The new plate of **emmeans** will display output with `(nothing)` in this situation. I also added a FAQ to explain this.

Comment: I meant "update" - changed to "plate" by auto-incorrect